How can I stick together a Manually entered column and a google form response column on google sheets?
I have a Google form that sends data to a Google Sheets spreadsheet.
In the spreadsheet, I manually entered a new column (Not in the form) for internal purposes, but when I need to sort the rows (by name, date, color, etc.) the manually entered data column doesn't sort, only the rows in the google form columns.
How can I attach the manually entered data to the Google form responses columns so that when sorting data, it'll all stay together?

Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?

It is never a good idea to manipulate the original form response data.  Instead, use other sheets to play with other data.
For example:

Don't add your new data column in the Form Responses 1 sheet, instead add Sheet2.
For each new value you add in Sheet2 also add a unique value from the Form Responses 1 data that indicates the response it is associated with.  This could be datetime value from the form response or even the row number of the record (in that case be cognizant of SORT order in subsequent formulas).
In Sheet2 or in a new Sheet3, you can join the data together.

